# Easy Fisher Exact Test on multiple runs

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, fishers-exact-test

I have a binary classifier problem with 18 samples to evaluate. To have less variance, I ran the same experiment 3 times, so I have 54 predictions.

Now I want to run a Fisher Exact Test, but is it valid to do it on the 54 predictions(3 runs) that I have?